# How to retrieve particular JsonObject irrespective of it's depth in Json?

Tags: java, json

During automation test run, I come across JsonObject like followin, let's call it `jsonObject`.

```js
{
    "434": {
        "Test1": {
            "id": "0001",
            "Name": "John"
        }
    },
    "435": {
        "Test2": {
            "id": "0002",
            "Name": "John"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve JsonObject for `Test1` and `Test2`. I can retrieve it like:

```
jsonObject.getJsonObject("434").getJsonObject("Test1");
jsonObject.getJsonObject("435").getJsonObject("Test2");
```

But values `434` and `435` are not constants. When I re-run test, this time those could be some different numbers. Hence I don't know what could be there next time instead of `434` and `435`

Is there any way, I can get JsonObject of `Test1` and `Test2` irrespective of `434` and `435` (something like `jsonObject.someMethod("Test1");`)?

I'm using `javax.json` library.

Comment: Get the keys of the top level object and loop over the values of their contents. Inside, you will loop over your "test" objects.

Comment: You should try jackson to convert your json into pojos. In your case all you need is a hashMap<String, SomeObject>. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: If we are plugging libraries... Why not try [Google gson](https://github.com/google/gson)? :-p If you want to discover more JSON libraries, you can check out the following blog post: [*Top 7 Open-Source JSON-Binding Providers Available Today*](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/top-7-open-source-json-binding-providers-available-today.html) Which is a year old, but contains informative information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonObject.keys()` to get an iterator of all property names in current JSON object. This will allow you to do something like this:

```
Iterable<String> keys = () -> jsonObject.keys();
List<JSONObject> nestedFilteredObjects = stream(keys.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(key -> jsonObject.getJSONObject(key).has("Test"))
        .map(key -> jsonObject.getJSONObject(key))
        .collect(toList());
```

Of course you still need to add try-catches for the json exceptions and consider what happens when the property is not a json object (`getJSONObject` will throw the exception).

Something like the code below should do. Please keep in mind that I did not test it and you can adapt it more to your needs - I don't know what possible jsons you may have in your tests:

```
private static List<JSONObject> getNestedTestObjects(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2MethodRef")
    Iterable<String> keys = () -> jsonObject.keys();
    return stream(keys.spliterator(), false)

            .map(key -> object(jsonObject, key))
            .filter(object -> object instanceof JSONObject)
            .map(object -> (JSONObject) object)

            .filter(object -> object.has("Test"))

            .map(object -> object(object, "Test"))
            .filter(object -> object instanceof JSONObject)
            .map(object -> (JSONObject) object)

            .collect(toList());
}

private static Object object(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
    try {
        return jsonObject.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your target object by passing in the key you are searching for. The method will handle traveling down to each child object to find the matching key. It will return the first match.

Also, you can retrieve all nested JSON objects at a desired depth by using a recursive routine as seen below. You choose the level and the method will add each `JsonObject` to a results list. The list is printed at the end.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.json.*;
import javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator;

public class JsonSearchUtilities {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonObject jsonObj = readJson("data.json");

        // Search for a JSON object by its key.
        System.out.println("===================\nSearch by Key\n===================");
        searchByKey(jsonObj, "Test2");

        // Search for a JSON objects by depth.
        System.out.println("\n===================\nSearch by Depth\n===================\n");
        searchFullDepth(jsonObj);
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // Main Routines
    // ========================================================================
    public static void searchByKey(JsonObject jsonObj, String key) {
        JsonObject json = getJsonByKey(jsonObj, key);
        String jsonStr = prettyPrint(json);

        System.out.println(jsonStr);
    }

    public static void searchFullDepth(JsonObject jsonObj) {
        JsonArray jsonArr = null;
        int depth = 0;

        do {
            jsonArr = getNestedObjects(jsonObj, depth);
            String jsonStr = prettyPrint(jsonArr);
            System.out.printf("Depth = %d%n%s%s%n%n", depth, "---------", jsonStr);
            depth++;
        } while (jsonArr != null && !jsonArr.isEmpty());
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // Key Search - Search by key
    // ========================================================================
    public static JsonObject getJsonByKey(JsonObject jsonObj, String search) {
        return getJsonByKey(jsonObj, search, 10);
    }

    public static JsonObject getJsonByKey(JsonObject jsonObj, String search, int maxDepth) {
        return getJsonByKey(jsonObj, search, maxDepth, 0);
    }

    /** @private Inner recursive call. */
    private static JsonObject getJsonByKey(JsonObject jsonObj, String search, int maxDepth, int level) {
        if (level < maxDepth && jsonObj != null) {
            Object child = null;

            for (String key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
                child = jsonObj.get(key);

                if (child instanceof JsonObject) {
                    if (key.equals(search)) {
                        return (JsonObject) child;
                    }
                }
            }

            return getJsonByKey((JsonObject) child, search, maxDepth, level + 1);
        }

        return null;
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // Depth Search - Search by depth
    // ========================================================================
    public static JsonArray getNestedObjects(JsonObject jsonObj, int depth) {
        JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        getNestedObjects(jsonObj, builder, depth);

        return builder.build();
    }

    /** @private Inner recursive call. */
    private static void getNestedObjects(JsonObject jsonObj, JsonArrayBuilder builder, int level) {
        if (level == 0) {
            builder.add(jsonObj);
        }

        if (jsonObj != null) {
            for (String key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
                Object child = jsonObj.get(key);

                if (child instanceof JsonObject) {
                    getNestedObjects((JsonObject) child, builder, level - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // Utilities - Read and write
    // ========================================================================
    private static InputStream getInputStream(String filename, boolean isResource) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (isResource) {
            ClassLoader loader = JsonSearchUtilities.class.getClassLoader();
            return loader.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        } else {
            return new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
        }
    }

    public static JsonObject readJson(String filename) {
        InputStream stream = null;

        try {
            stream = getInputStream(filename, true);
            JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(stream);
            return reader.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String prettyPrint(JsonStructure json) {
        return jsonFormat(json, JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING);
    }

    public static String jsonFormat(JsonStructure json, String... options) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        Map<String, Boolean> config = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

        if (options != null) {
            for (String option : options) {
                config.put(option, true);
            }
        }

        JsonWriterFactory writerFactory = Json.createWriterFactory(config);
        JsonWriter jsonWriter = writerFactory.createWriter(stringWriter);

        jsonWriter.write(json);
        jsonWriter.close();

        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

#### Output

```js
===================
Search by Key
===================

{
    "id":"0002",
    "Name":"John"
}

===================
Search by Depth
===================

Depth = 0
---------
[
    {
        "434":{
            "Test1":{
                "id":"0001",
                "Name":"John"
            }
        },
        "435":{
            "Test2":{
                "id":"0002",
                "Name":"John"
            }
        }
    }
]

Depth = 1
---------
[
    {
        "Test1":{
            "id":"0001",
            "Name":"John"
        }
    },
    {
        "Test2":{
            "id":"0002",
            "Name":"John"
        }
    }
]

Depth = 2
---------
[
    {
        "id":"0001",
        "Name":"John"
    },
    {
        "id":"0002",
        "Name":"John"
    }
]

Depth = 3
---------
[
]
```